# check label font-color in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I am little new to Jquery, I have search net for my solution but havent got anything.

In JQuery I need to check what is the font-color of label.

I m working on .aspx page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css function:

```
$('label#id').css('color');
```

Answer (score 1):

try

http://jsfiddle.net/mM2XW/57/

HTML

```
<label for="model">Test1</label>
<input type="text" name="model" id="model">
<input id="changeColor" type="button" value="Change Label Color">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function changeColor(id, newColor) {
  $("#" + id).prev().css("color", newColor);
}

$('#changeColor').click(function() {
    changeColor('model', 'red');
});
```